# Set up the same radio button after clicking edit

Tags: java, html, forms, web-services, web

I have a form where I input some data and choose from a group of radio buttons one radio button. 
Than I click submit and go to the next page where entered data are displayed. On that page I have also buttons Edit and Confirm. When I click edit I return to the next page. I would like that all previously entered information are displayed in the input boxes and that previously chosen radio button is set up too. So I actually was able to set up the same info in the input boxes because I use CDI beans for that. I have a problem with radio button. CDI bean reembers which radio button I choose but when I click Edit button it doesn't mark radio button I choose previously.

So how can I solve this problem?
I use simple HTML for the pages and Java code. For your information I don't use JSF. Maybe there are some HTML tricks you could advice me.

I tried to use "checked" for radio button so I know that one radio button will be marked by default but  it is not what I want. I choose one particular button and that particular button should be marked when I use "edit" button.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Q: Is your UI an HTML form?  Q: Is your form being submitted to a Java servlet, who's reading the form data from a servlet request object?  It sounds like maybe you want to use a .JSP to generate your HTML dynamically (instead of having a static page)?

Comment: @FoggyDay Yes. My UI is in HTML form. My first page is index.html where I have the link to the next page. When I click the link it takes me to the page where I have a form to fill out. That page is included in the Java Servlet code. When the form is submitted it takes me to the next page where previously entered information is displayed.

Comment: THat page is also includes in another Java Servlet. ON that page you have also two buttons "Edit" and "Confirm". When I click edit it takes me to the previous page where is the form. The previously entered data should be shown there. It all happen thank to use of CDI beans. I have another class that I use SessionScoped and Named annotations. In the classes where I use servlets I use Inject annotation. It all works but my problem is with the radio button. You know I am not suppose to use JSP. I know it would be easier to use JSP but its' not my idea to use only HTML only my instructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem

```
@Inject 
Controller con; 

String bank = con.getUserBank();

if(bank.equals("BofA")) {
  out.println("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"bank\" value=\"BofA" checked>Bank of America");
} else {
  out.println("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"bank\" value=\"BofA">Bank of America");
}
```

Now after editing my chosen radio button is marked as previous answer before editing.